# VMplayer closes on start of vm

Tags: vmware, vmware-player

I want to install ubuntu as a virtual machine on my ubuntu machine.
The version of the host system is: `Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS`
The iso I want to install is: `ubuntu-18.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso`
So I downloaded vmplayer and ran:

```
sudo bash VMware-Player-15.5.1-15018445.x86_64.bundle
```

When I run `vmplayer` in terminal, I get

```
[AppLoader] Use shipped Linux kernel AIO access library.
An up-to-date "libaio" or "libaio1" package from your system is preferred.
[AppLoader] Use shipped Linux kernel AIO access library.
An up-to-date "libaio" or "libaio1" package from your system is preferred.
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/etc/vmware/hostd/proxy.xml"

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:11:09.896: Inserting action group 'Base' into UI manager which already has a group with this name

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:11:09.896: Inserting action group 'WindowActions' into UI manager which already has a group with this name
```

I select "Create new virtual machine", fill everything out, choose `/home/me/vmware/Ubuntu 64-bit` as location. I choose 10GB disk capacity and "Store virtual disk as a single file".

there is more output on the terminal:

```
Unknown file type (unallocated) /home/t/vmware/Ubuntu 64-bit/boot/.. - ignoring and continuing.
Size of boot image is 4 sectors -> No emulation
 18.55% done, estimate finish Sun Mar  1 19:15:37 2020
 37.01% done, estimate finish Sun Mar  1 19:15:37 2020
 55.54% done, estimate finish Sun Mar  1 19:15:37 2020
 74.01% done, estimate finish Sun Mar  1 19:15:37 2020
 92.51% done, estimate finish Sun Mar  1 19:15:37 2020
Total translation table size: 2048
Total rockridge attributes bytes: 0
Total directory bytes: 4380
Path table size(bytes): 40
Max brk space used 0
27033 extents written (52 MB)
```

Now when I start the machine("power on"), the window closes and the terminal says (always from 1 to 5):

```
(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.867: removable-device-0: missing action removable-device-0

...

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.867: removable-device-5: missing action removable-device-5

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.867: removable-device-0-choose-image: missing action removable-device-0-choose-image

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.867: removable-device-0-edit: missing action removable-device-0-edit

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.867: removable-device-1-choose-image: missing action removable-device-1-choose-image

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.867: removable-device-1-edit: missing action removable-device-1-edit

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.867: removable-device-2-choose-image: missing action removable-device-2-choose-image

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.867: removable-device-2-edit: missing action removable-device-2-edit

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.867: removable-device-3-connect: missing action removable-device-3-connect

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.867: removable-device-3-nic-bridged: missing action removable-device-3-nic-bridged

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.867: removable-device-3-nic-nat: missing action removable-device-3-nic-nat

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.867: removable-device-3-nic-host-only: missing action removable-device-3-nic-host-only

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.867: removable-device-3-edit: missing action removable-device-3-edit

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.867: removable-device-4connect: missing action removable-device-4connect

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.867: removable-device-4-edit: missing action removable-device-4-edit

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.867: removable-device-5connect: missing action removable-device-5connect

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.867: removable-device-5-edit: missing action removable-device-5-edit

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.868: removable-device-0: missing action removable-device-0

...

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.868: removable-device-5: missing action removable-device-5

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.868: removable-device-0-choose-image: missing action removable-device-0-choose-image

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.868: removable-device-0-edit: missing action removable-device-0-edit

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.868: removable-device-1-choose-image: missing action removable-device-1-choose-image

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.868: removable-device-1-edit: missing action removable-device-1-edit

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.868: removable-device-2-choose-image: missing action removable-device-2-choose-image

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.868: removable-device-2-edit: missing action removable-device-2-edit

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.868: removable-device-3-connect: missing action removable-device-3-connect

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.868: removable-device-3-nic-bridged: missing action removable-device-3-nic-bridged

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.868: removable-device-3-nic-nat: missing action removable-device-3-nic-nat

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.868: removable-device-3-nic-host-only: missing action removable-device-3-nic-host-only

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.868: removable-device-3-edit: missing action removable-device-3-edit

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.868: removable-device-4connect: missing action removable-device-4connect

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.868: removable-device-4-edit: missing action removable-device-4-edit

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.868: removable-device-5connect: missing action removable-device-5connect

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.868: removable-device-5-edit: missing action removable-device-5-edit

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.870: removable-device-0: missing action removable-device-0

...

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.871: removable-device-5: missing action removable-device-5

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.871: removable-device-0-choose-image: missing action removable-device-0-choose-image

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.871: removable-device-0-edit: missing action removable-device-0-edit

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.871: removable-device-1-choose-image: missing action removable-device-1-choose-image

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.871: removable-device-1-edit: missing action removable-device-1-edit

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.871: removable-device-2-choose-image: missing action removable-device-2-choose-image

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.871: removable-device-2-edit: missing action removable-device-2-edit

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.871: removable-device-3-connect: missing action removable-device-3-connect

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.871: removable-device-3-nic-bridged: missing action removable-device-3-nic-bridged

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.871: removable-device-3-nic-nat: missing action removable-device-3-nic-nat

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.871: removable-device-3-nic-host-only: missing action removable-device-3-nic-host-only

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.871: removable-device-3-edit: missing action removable-device-3-edit

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.871: removable-device-4connect: missing action removable-device-4connect

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.871: removable-device-4-edit: missing action removable-device-4-edit

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.871: removable-device-5connect: missing action removable-device-5connect

(vmplayer:19995): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:27.871: removable-device-5-edit: missing action removable-device-5-edit
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Enabling hardware virtualization in BIOS solved the problem for me.